# Error from installing Moose locally

Tags: perl, moose

I was able to run the following code on my local machine where I have a power of sudo"

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package Cat
{
    use Moose;
    has 'name', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str';

}

my $test_obj = Cat->new(name => "kitty");

print $test_obj->name()."\n";
```

result :

```
$perl Cat.pl
kitty
```

But when I ran the exact same code in other machines where I do not have sudo,
I get the following error:

```
syntax error at Cat.pl line 5, near "{
    "
Execution of Cat.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Why does this happen?

I installed the Module using cpanm on all of my three machines, one with sudo and the two without sudo(I installed them locally). The versions of perl are :

```
machine 1(worked, has sudo) : (v5.14.2) built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int
machine 2(did not work, no sudo previlage) : perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
machine 3(did not work, no sudo previlage) : v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

So it seems like it has to do with shared library or something, but I cannot figure out exactly why it doesn't work on the two machines. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `package { ... }` syntax you're trying to use was added in perl 5.14.0 (released in May 2011).

If you want to run on perl 5.12 and older, change your code to look like:

```
{
    package Cat;
    use Moose;
    has 'name' => (...);
    # etc.
}

my $test_obj = Cat->new(...);
# etc.
```

The `package` declaration won't leak outside of the braces, so the code at the bottom will be running in package `main`, and `my` or `our` variables will stay inside of the block as well.

Comment: Or `{ package Cat; ... }`, since the code at the bottom isn't supposed to be part of the package.